# Kubernetes: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority, possibly because of ECDSA verification failure

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, lets-encrypt, sslhandshakeexception

I am new in Kubernetes and stuck on the issue. I was trying to renew letsencrypt SSL certificate. But when I try to get certificate by running following command

```
kubectl get certificate
```

System throwing this exception

```
Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=Certificate failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.default.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "cert-manager-webhook-ca")
```

I have checked the pods also

[image]

The "cert-manager-webhook" is in running state. When I check logs of this pod, I get the following response

[image]

I have also tried to apply cluster-issuer after deleting it but face same issue

```
kubectl apply -f cluster-issuer.yaml
```

[image]

I also have done R&D about this but could not find any suitable solution. Whats the issue here? Can someone please help me regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: seems to be related https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3338

Comment: I have already checked that issue. ""cert-manager-cainjector" pod status is  "CrashLoopBackOff". May be that pod causing this issue? Any idea about that? @mario

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with "**cert-manager-cainjector**" pod status which was "**CrashLoopBackOff**" due to FailedMount as **secret** was not found for mounting. I have created that secret and after that it start working fine.

Comment: Can you explain how you created the secret?

Comment: I have used this command 'kubectl create secret generic azure-secret --from-literal=azurestorageaccountname=xxxxxx --from-literal=azurestorageaccountkey=xxxxxxxx'

Answer (score 2):

if you are using webhook, check if you have injected the ca, if not you could do it using:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
...
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/inject-ca-from: "<namespace>/<certificate_name>"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was attempting to install an older version of `cert-manager` onto my cluster, and Simply pulling the latest version of `cert-manger` (1.10.1 at time of writing) and installing that worked.

---

When attempting to install an older version of `cert-manager` I saw the following error from the `cainjector` pod.

> error registering secret controller: no matches for kind "MutatingWebhookConfiguration" in version "admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"

I assume that the API **admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1** has been removed between K8s versions 1.21 and 1.24, and that's why I encountered an issue.